# Need help solving a combinatorics problem...

Tags: combinatorics

The eleven members of the soccer team are posing for their team picture. Five players will stand and the other six players will kneel in front of them. In how many ways can the 5 standing players be chosen and arranged from left to right?

a.) 120
b.) 90
c.) 55,440
d.) 39,916,800

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem and can share what you have tried? Regards

Answer (score 2):

(1) We have $11$ players, and can *choose* $5$ of them for standing. There are

$\quad\binom{11}{5}\;$ ways of doing this. That just selects $5$ team members for the standing row.

(2) These five chosen players can ***then*** be positioned in $5!$ ways.

So we have $$5! \times \binom{11}{5} = 5!\left(\dfrac{11!}{5!\cdot 6!}\right) = \dfrac{11!}{6!} = 11\times 10 \times 9\times 8\times 7$$ ways of choosing and arranging these players from left to right.